# How to Split the Contents of a Single Pandas Dataframe Column into Multiple New Columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

Let's say I have data of the records of two sports teams.

```
d = {'Team': [1, 2], 'Record': ['5-0', '3-2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    Team    Record
0     1      5-0
1     2      3-2
```

I want to split and append the record into new columns for each team like so:

```
d = {'Team': [1, 2], 'Record': ['5-0', '3-2'], 'Wins': [5, 3], 'Losses' : [0, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df


  Team  Record  Wins    Losses
0   1    5-0     5         0
1   2    3-2     3         2
```

The data in the Records column is an object, due to the hyphen.

```
(df.dtypes)

Team       int64
Record    object
dtype: object
```

How would I go about doing this? Would it be some sort of regex, and then a list comprehension to go through each row of the Record column? I would like to do this for around 400 teams in a dataframe. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use pandas string methods, specifically, [str split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas.Series.str.split) and [str get](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html#pandas.Series.str.get), and [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) the extracts to new columns :

```
    df = (df
         .assign(Wins= df.Record.str.split('-').str.get(0),
                 Losses = df.Record.str.split('-').str.get(-1)
            )
          )

df


  Team  Record  Wins    Losses
0   1    5-0     5         0
1   2    3-2     3         2
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data are well behaved enough you can use `Series.str.extract` with named capture groups `(Number)-(Number)`. Then concat back.

```
pd.concat([df, df['Record'].str.extract(r'(?P<Wins>\d)-(?P<Losses>\d)')], axis=1)
#   Team Record Wins Losses
#0     1    5-0    5      0
#1     2    3-2    3      2
```

Comment: Wow, I wasn't aware of this feature : extract + capture group naming. Good to know :)